# Conflict between `booktabs` and `arydshln` packages

Tags: tables, booktabs, arydshln

Please see the MWE below and its result. I didn't use the `arydshln` package in the example, but I have to use it somewhere else in the same document. As you see, there is something wrong with the vertical border lines in the table. If I don't use one of the `arydshln` and `booktabs` packages, it displays correctly.

Is there any workaround here? I'm looking for one of the following:

1. A method to prevent the wrong display with both packages used.
2. An alternative to the nice formatting and `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` from the `booktabs` package.
3. An alternative to the `arydshln` package to draw dashed lines in math arrays (vectors, matrices).

Thank you for the help.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c | r r }
\toprule
    & 123 & 456 \\
\midrule
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{blah blah blah }\\
\midrule
    abc & def & hij \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

ADDED--

After some experiments, I found `multicolumn` is not a key. When I replaced it by a regular row, it still displays wrong.

Comment: If you want to have vertical rules in a tabular, don't use `booktabs` commands: the package is built under the assumption that vertical rules are *A Bad Thing*. On the other hand, if you stick to `\hline` or `\cline` in tables where vertical rules are needed, then you can still load `booktabs` and employ its commands for other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [easybmat package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easybmat), which makes it easy to put dashed lines inside matrices.

Answer (score 3):

**ARRAY**
If you read the documentation of `booktabs`, you will see that `booktabs` does not support vertical lines. You may try the package [array](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/array) and the command `extrarowheight`. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ c | r r }
\hline
    & 123 & 456 \\
\hline
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{blah blah blah }\\
\hline
    abc & def & hij \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**TABU**
Or you can try the package [tabu](http://tug.ctan.org/pkg/tabu), which support all types of lines directly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,tabu}

\begin{document}

\tabulinesep=1.2mm
\begin{tabu} to .3\columnwidth [c]{X[c] | X[r] X[r]}
\firsthline[3pt]
    & 123 & 456 \\
\tabucline [1pt on 1.5pt off 2pt]{1-3}
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{blah blah blah }\\
\tabucline [1pt on 1.5pt off 2pt]{1-3}
    abc & def & hij \\
\lasthline[3pt]
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

[image: tabu]